# How in swift one should use DI when conforming to a protocol with associated type?

Tags: swift, generics, dependency-injection, protocols, associated-types

I want to achieve something like this in swift:

```swift
protocol P {}
protocol P1: P {}
class P1Impl: P1 {}

protocol PBase {
  associatedtype T: P
  var prop: T { get }
}

struct S: PBase {
  typealias T = P1 // <---- The problem

  // This property is got via DI, so I don't know
  // the actual type of it.
  @Injected var prop: P1
}
```

Now the problem is that this code won't compile and the reason is the line `typealias T = P1`. The compiler wants to know the actual type instead of `P1` (while I don't have that type).

I would understand this restriction if the protocol `P` had a required static property. In that case we can get the value of that property without any instance so the actual type is really needed. However there is no such a property in my case.

Anyway, I like swift and want to solve this task in a swifty way. What is the best practice for this case?

P.S.

I thought generics could help:

```swift
struct S<T: P1>: PBase {
  var prop: T
}
```

However in this case also I don't know the type of `T` when creating an instance of `S` because of DI which returns a protocol.

In case of `any P` the code still doesn't compile, I get the same error as before:

```swift
protocol PBase {
  var prop: P { get }
}

struct S: PBase {
  @Injected var prop: P1
}
```

But there is a workaround, which I think is not the nicest solution.

```swift
protocol PBase {
  var prop: P { get }
}

struct S: PBase {
  @Injected var prop1: P1
  var prop: P { prop1 }
}
```

Also everything gets worse when another protocol which should be inherited from `PBase` is needed.

Comment: Can `P` and `P1` be `@objc`? Adding `@objc` guarantees "no static requirement", and would allow your code to compile. Also, perhaps `PBase` doesn't need an associated type at all? What's wrong with `var prop: any P { get }`?

Comment: `@objc` does the trick, thank you for this solution. However it would be nice to have a solution in pure swift using the language constructions.

Comment: I edited the question and added the `any P` case.

Comment: The workaround with `prop1` is what I had in mind. If you don't like it, I can't think of anything else.

Comment: I think the solution with `any P` is the best one yet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, I do believe it might be worth checking out the `any P` return value and whether or not your `associatedtype` requirement is actually needed. And otherwise you could try to use type erasure:

```
struct AnyP1: P1 {
    var actual: any P1

    init(_ actual: any P1) {
        self.actual = actual
    }
}
```

This wraps the P1 implementation into a known type, which will also conform to the `P1` protocol. Then in your `S` object, you should do the following:

```
struct S: PBase {
    typealias T: AnyP1

    var prop: T
}

// Or shorthand

struct S: PBase {
    var prop: AnyP1
}
```

Your `S` will now always know what the type of `T` will be, and the type erasure will contain the actual underlying protocol value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yeah, type erasure can help but if I have many classes/structs like `S` that should conform to `PBase` is it good to create so many type erasure components? Also how should I use (register/resolve) my structs/classes when using type erasure?

Comment: @as_danmark if you'd want, you could make an `AnyPBase` too, there's no reason not to do it. I do however think that you might be better of using an alternative approach. Again, are you sure using a `protocol` is the only way? Have you thought about subclassing? Are you sure you're not overengineering? Sometimes it's best to take one step back and see the bigger picture

Comment: I always tend to follow the rule to use protocols at first and only then think about subclassing. Thank you for the solution but I don't think that subclassing and so many number of type erasure components are good. As you said that would lead to overengineering. I'd rather use `any P` with an additional property or maybe `@objc`.

Comment: The good thing is that soon with SwiftMacro you'll be able to generate the boxing instead of writing it yourself :)